# DFS (Обход графа в глубину)

Tags: python, python-3.x, графы

Дан неориентированный граф без кратный ребер и петель. Программа выдает данную ошибку:

```
File "dfsbfs.py", line 12, in dfs
    new_vertices = [j for j in adj[u] if j not in visited]
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Не понимаю почему так происходит.

```
n = int(input('Vertices: '))
m = int(input('Edges: '))
adj = []
for i in range(m):
    adj.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
def dfs(v):
    visited = {v}
    to_explore = [v]
    while to_explore:
        u = to_explore.pop()
        print (u)
        new_vertices = [j for j in adj[u] if j not in visited]
        to_explore.extend(new_vertices)
        visited.update(new_vertices)
dfs(0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `to_explore` у вас список **вершин**, которые нужно ещё посетить. А в `adj` - список **рёбер** между вершинами, при этом вы берёте из `to_explore` индексы **вершин** и обращаетесь с этим индексом к `adj`, поэтому если у вас **вершин** больше, чем **рёбер**, индекс этот выходит за пределы списка **рёбер** `adj`.

Как конкретно починить ваш алгоритм я не разбирался, но вам нужно как минимум:

- Разобраться, где у вас хранятся вершины, а где рёбра
- Назвать все переменные соответственно этому, чтобы не нужно было думать-вспоминать, где у вас что

После этого проще будет уже разбираться с алгоритмом, просто приводя в соответствие при манипуляциях с данными чтобы вершины были к вершинам, а рёбра к рёбрам.

Comment: +1. `adj` судя по алгоритму хранит список смежности, т.е. `adj[i]` хранит список вершин, для которые есть ребро из вершины `i`. Значит длина списка `adj` должна быть `n`. По-моему, в этом проблема.